# Converting String to long in Java does not work

Tags: java, long-integer

How can I convert a String that was loaded from a xml file to a `long`? Is there any specification for the String put into the function

```
Long.parseLong(String s, int radix)
```

Comment: Sometimes you just have to read the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: Well, I did it.. When I tried to do the way I initialize string with 

`String s = 12345;`

then I convert it without any problem. I have this issue only when I am trying to convert string which was read from xml file.

Comment: Probably I have problem that the string I have loaded from xml file does not contains parsable long - according to documentation.

Comment: And is there a specific reason why you're not showing (part of) the content of this xml file?

Comment: Re-read the documentation.  Then read the documentation for `String.trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in **10** as the radix (integers, doubles, longs et.c are base 10).

```
String s = "123456789";
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(s, 10));
// Prints 123456789
```

You'd use base 2 for binary and base 16 for hex

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already know that this way exists. I think there is problem with String loaded from the xml file.

Comment: Are you trying to read xml and then convert node value to long yourself? Why not use JAXB libraries to read xml into pojo?